# How to quote this dynamic SQL properly?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic, exec, quotes

I am trying to write some dynamic SQL like below:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC (''

DECLARE @type NVARCHAR(32);

IF DB_NAME() IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')
BEGIN
    SET @type = ''System'';
END

SELECT @type;

'')'
```

But I think the quoting is not working, as I get the error:

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'master'.**

Any tips on what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double escape everything inside `EXEC('')`, e.g.

```
IF DB_NAME() IN (''''master'''',''''model'''',''''msdb'''',''''tempdb'''')
```

The first escape is for `sp_msforeachdb`, as it stands currently (with just one) you end up with something like:

```
USE [Master];
EXEC ('IF DB_NAME() IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
...
```

What you need is to end up with:'

```
USE [Master];
EXEC ('IF DB_NAME() IN (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'')
...
```

So your full SQL becomes:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC (''

DECLARE @type NVARCHAR(32);

IF DB_NAME() IN (''''master'''',''''model'''',''''msdb'''',''''tempdb'''')
BEGIN
    SET @type = ''''System'''';
END

SELECT @type;

'')'
```

However, it is not necessary to use `EXEC` at all:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; 
    DECLARE @type NVARCHAR(32);

    IF DB_NAME() IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')
    BEGIN
        SET @type = ''System'';
    END

    SELECT @type;'
```